# Convergence of a sequence in L2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm working on this problem that I'm kind of struggling with.

**Statement:**

Consider: $ h_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}n^4( (x-1/2) + 1/n^3)&\mbox{if }\,1/2-1/n^3\leq x< 1/2\\ -n^4((x-1/2)-1/n^3)&\mbox{if }\,1/2\leq x\leq1/2+1/n^3 \\ 0&\mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right. $

Show that $h_n$ converges to the 0 function as $n\to\infty$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$.

**Attempt:**

case 1) for x=0

x is in the support for h_n for n=1,2 but then once n=3 $x=0\notin[1/2-1/3^3,1/2[$  nor $x=0\notin[1/2,1/2+1/3^3]$ which leads me to believe that $ h_n(x=0) \to 0$ BUT the hint in the questions says to start the problem by showing that $ h_n(x=0) \to \infty$ .

So here I am at the beginning of the problem ... a little stumped. Your guys' genius insight is always appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by null function?

Comment: to the 0 function

Comment: At least the hint contradicts with the question. How can $h_n(0)\to \infty$ and $h_n(x)\to 0$? Also note that $h_n({1\over 2})=n\to \infty$

Comment: well maybe my logic is wrong? And I can see if x=1/2 that is true. But the question is asking whether it converges in $L^2$ i.e. I need to show that: the square norm between the converging function $ | h_n - h |_{L^2} \to 0 $

Comment: Have you tried integrating $h_n^2$ over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yeah - it's just this hint to the problem is throwing me off and seems counter intuitive.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to figure out if the hint is wrong or whether there is something I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Note that $0 \leq h_n \leq n1(|x-1/2| < n^{-3})$.

So $\|h_n\|_2^2 \leq n^2\lambda((1/2-n^{-3},1/2+n^{-3})) \leq 2n^2n^{-3}=2/n$, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading your parentheses statements - are you saying $0\leq h_n\leq n1$ for $|x-1/2|<n^{-3}$ (and your second line is using a similar notation....) Or are you saying $n1$ and lambda are functions of the interval in the bracket

Comment: Or are you literally multiplying by that interval

Comment: No, $1(|x-1/2| < \alpha)$ is the function that is $0$ if $|x-1/2| \geq \alpha$ and $1$ if $|x-1/2| < \alpha$.

Comment: Is that a typical notation? Is this not a Heaviside function? Your notation is sort of hard to follow.